# Why the shadow for UIView is not working as I expected?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to have the shadow surround a View, but for some reason, the shadow only appears on the top and left side of the View, below is my code and view image. Can someone tell me what I did wrong and how should I change my code, so that the shadow will also appear on the right and bottom? Thank you.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    layer.shadowRadius = 10
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:1, height: 1)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)
}
```

[the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGfQ8.png)

Comment: Change the shadow offset to 0,0

Comment: I just changed the shadow offset to 0,0   It did not work

Comment: It’s probably there, you just need to adjust your radius to start to see it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong there. Make sure you are not changing something elsewhere. This shouldn't be the issue, but just to be sure, try `layer.masksToBounds = false`

Comment: Try ommitting that last line (layer.shadowPath = CGPath(rect: bounds, transform: nil)). And yes, layer.masksToBounds = false